# Show that the group $(\Bbb R,+)/(\Bbb Z,+)$ has non-trivial finite subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

> Show that the group $(\Bbb R,+)/(\Bbb Z,+)$ has non-trivial finite subgroups.

The group is

$$(\Bbb R,+)/(\Bbb Z,+) = \{a + \Bbb Z \mid a \in \Bbb R\},$$

but I think all of the cosets are infinite? For example with $3+\Bbb Z = \{\dots,3,4,5,6, \dots \}$.

How can I get a finite subgroup when the cosets are of the form $a + \Bbb Z$ for $a \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: Consider the subgroup generated by $\frac{1}{2}+\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Try to generate a subgroup with non-integer number. Actually you have mentioned a trivial subgroup above because $3=0\in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: A group has a nontrivial finite subgroup if and only if it has a nontrivial element of finite order. That makes the problem easier.

Comment: You confuse a subgroup of $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ with a coset of $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb R$.  These are completely different things.

Comment: So am I to consider for example $\langle 1/2 + \Bbb Z \rangle = \{a+ \Bbb Z + \langle 1/2 + \Bbb Z \rangle \mid a + \Bbb Z \in \Bbb R / \Bbb Z\}?$

Comment: @SleepWalker yes.

Comment: @SleepWalker Note that that right hand side that you wrote is not the subgroup generated by $1/2+\mathbb{Z}$. The subgroup generated by this would be adding this with itself any integer (positive, zero, and negative taking inverse) number of times, or in other words the multiples of $1/2+\mathbb{Z}$. So, that would be $\{1/2+\mathbb{Z},(1/2+\mathbb{Z})+(1/2+\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}\}$. All other multiples are equal to one of those two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $n\in\Bbb N.$ We have

$$n\left(\frac{1}{n}+\Bbb Z\right)=\Bbb Z.$$

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the cosets are infinite is irrelevant: if you consider the group $G=\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ under multiplication and its subgroup $H=\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ of the positive rationals, then $G/H$ is finite, notwithstanding that the cosets are infinite.

If you consider $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ defined by
$$
f(x)=\cos(2\pi x)+i\sin(2\pi x)=e^{2\pi ix}
$$
(the codomain is the multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers) then $f$ is a group homomorphism and its kernel is $\mathbb{Z}$. Its image is $\mathbb{T}$, the group of modulus $1$ complex numbers. Thus
$$
\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{T}
$$
and the group $\mathbb{T}$ has several finite subgroups, for instance the set of $n$th roots of $1$, where $n>0$.